# Accept JSON in Rails Controller when wrong format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, devise

I have the following in my Registrations Controller:

```
class Api::V1::RegistrationsController  < ApplicationController

  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
  respond_to :json

  def create

    user = User.new(params[user_params])

    if user.save
      render :json => user.as_json(:auth_token=>user.authentication_token, :email=>user.email), :status=>201
      return
    else
      warden.custom_failure!
      render :json => user.errors, :status=>422
    end
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :name, :phone, :acknowledgement)
  end

end
```

I realize this expects my JSON to be in the form of

```
{user:{email:user@example.com,name:"anotheruser"}}
```

However the JSON is being sent as

```
{email:user@example.com, name:"anotheruser"}
```

I don't know how to target those params. What is the syntax for that?
Also, is there a special way to handle that format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected json you got would be a hash of hashes, but you are only getting back a hash, is what it sounds like.

Given this, you don't need to require :user since :user isn't there.  Just do this.

params.permit(:email, :password, :name, :phone, :acknowledgement) if params.present?

present? will check to ensure params is not nil or blank/empty.  You could raise an error, if you wanted, if the present? check fails.

Comment: Check my update.  I misunderstood the question at first.  I thought you were having trouble accessing a hash within a hash.  Now I see that you just have a hash, not a hash of hashes.  Don't expect a hash of hashes if all you have is a hash.  You got what you did because require(:user) didn't find a :user key, and this is supported by the json you say you are actually receiving.

Comment: if you think you may sometimes get a hash of hashes with the user: key, then you could do something like... 
if params.present?
  if params[:user]
    params[:user].permit(...)
  else
    params.permit(...)
  end
end

Comment: That works.
Also works if I use:

    params.require[:registration].permit(:email, :password, :name, :phone, :acknowledgment)

Since rails seems to also wrap the hash within the name of the controller